# mount exfat warning

Tags: mount

Using Xubuntu 14.04. I mounted an external drive which has multiple partitions one of them is of type exFat and I am mounting it using the command below I get a warning that not cleanly mounted,

```
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdc6 /media/exfat/
FUSE exfat 1.0.1
WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
ahmed@xubuntu14:~$ sudo unmount /media/exfat/
sudo: unmount: command not found
```

Then I try to unmount it from file manager. it says failed to unmount exfat it is not in fstab are you not root ? can someone please advise how to unmount it again and mount it cleanly ?

Thanks,
Ahmed

Comment: there is no such command called unmount it should be  umount . sudo umount /media/exfat/

Answer (score 11):

This message indicates that volume may not have unmounted properly when turning the machine off

This can occur if the system is powered off without shutting down.

To unmount the volume you should run these commands:

```
sudo -i
umount /dev/sdc6
```

To diagnose any errors then you can use this command:

```
sudo -i
fsck.exfat /dev/sdc6
```

To repair errors should use testdisk.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step